# How to give directory and file permissions to a web server

Tags: permissions, webserver

I'm a Linux newbie. I'm doing a project that uses the gosmore routing engine. In one of my email to the developer about a certain problem, he replied to me that to solve the problem:

"I think you will have to move gosmore directory to a home directory and give the webserver read and execute rights. On my Ubuntu installation this is the /home/lambertus/gosmore and my webpages run in /home/lambertus/public_html/yours."

I did move the needed files to my home directory, and CHMOD it using this command:

`chmod -R 755 gosmore/`

The thing is, when I "ls -l" for the gosmore directory, it displays that I had had already set the permission correctly (drwxr-xr-x...). But when I check Permissions in the gosmore directory (right-click > Properties), the permissions are still not set. Because of these, my gosmore installation doesn't still work. What can I do to truly set the permissions that I need for the directories? Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: The only true way is that of the console. I mean, chmod and ls are likely right not nautilus (the right-click thing). If ls says that the permission are set, the permissions are set.

Comment: @Javier: I disagree, Nautilus will show the same as `ls` (if it didn't, there would be 1000s of bug reports about that).

Comment: @jalbautista: where (on what) did you right-click to check permissions in "Properties"?

Comment: Also check to see if your folder is enabled if your not logged in. I have seen people's home directories get unmounted when they log off which could result in the same issue, that your seeing.

Comment: @JanC: on the file/directory I am checking.

Comment: I restarted my laptop and now it works. I do not know why it didn't work for the first time. Maybe I miss something there :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're looking at the same directory. Nautilus (the GUI) and `ls` (in the terminal) will show the same permissions. Where did you end up putting the `gosmer` directory? Usually this needs to be `/home/USER/public_html/gosmer` for the webserver to see it as `http://localhost/~USER/gosmer/`. To enable `public_html`, use `sudo a2enmod user_dir`.

Finally, is your webserver configured to run the language that gosmer uses? For example, PHP would need `libapache2-mod-php` installed, and if gosmer uses CGI, you'd need to enable the CGI module (`sudo a2enmod cgi`) and allow it (add `ExecCGI` to the `Options` directive for your virtual host in the Apache configurations. For example:

```
<Directory /somewhere>
  AllowOverride All
  Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec ExecCGI
  IndexOptions NameWidth=*
<Directory>
```

This may need to be done in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf` if you're using `public_html` as the target.